# PHP - Searching keywords in a string and enhancing the quality and accuracy of extracted keywords

Tags: php, search

I have a piece of PHP code as follows:

```
$Keywords = array(
            ', JOE.' => '1',
            ', JOE' => '2',
            'JOE' => '3',
            'JOE.' => '4',
            '/JOE' => '5',
            '/JOE/' => '6',
            'JOE/.' => '7',
            ',JOE.' => '8'
    );
$Text = "JOE is JOE is JOE is JOE is JOE is JOE is JOE. Hello , JOE. Hey ,JOE. Come on , JOE. Dude,JOE/. Shut up ,JOE. What is the meaning of /JOE/? Of course, JOE";

extract_keyword ($Keywords, $Text);

function extract_keyword ($Keywords, $Text){
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

    uksort($Keywords, function ($a, $b) {
        $as = mb_strlen($a);
        $bs = mb_strlen($b);

        if ($as > $bs) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if ($bs > $as) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    });

    $Keywords_ci = array();

    foreach ($Keywords as $k => $v) {
        $Keywords_ci[$k] = $v;
    }

    $re = '/\b(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($keyword) {
        return preg_quote($keyword, '/');
    }, array_keys($Keywords))) . ')\b/i';

    $KeywordArrayKey = array();
    $KeywordArrayValue = array();
    $NewArray = array();
    preg_match_all($re, $Text, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $keyword) {
        $KeywordArrayKey[] = $keyword;
        $KeywordArrayValue[] = $Keywords_ci[$keyword];
        if(!empty($keyword) && !empty($Keywords_ci[$keyword])) {
        $NewArray[] = array($keyword => $Keywords_ci[$keyword]); 
        }
    } 
    print_r($NewArray) ."<br><br>";
}
```

The code echos the below:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[1] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[2] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[4] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[5] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[6] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[7] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[8] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[9] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[10] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[11] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[12] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[13] => Array ( [, JOE] => 2 ) )
```

As you can see, the problem is that the code is not accurate enough to extract the `$keywords` where there are keywords, such as `', JOE.' => '1' or 'JOE/.' => '7'`. In fact, my goal is to exactly separate the `'/JOE' => '5'` from `'/JOE/' => '6'` or `'JOE.' => '4'` and etc. Could you please take a look at the code and let me know how to enhance the quality/accuracy of the extracted keywords? thanks for your help.

Note 1: `print_r($Keywords_ci);` prints the `Array ( [, JOE.] => 1 [JOE/.] => 7 [,JOE.] => 8 [, JOE] => 2 [/JOE/] => 6 [JOE.] => 4 [/JOE] => 5 [JOE] => 3 )`, but what I'm looking for is to echo all instances of the available keywords such as `'/JOE/' => '6'` or `',JOE.' => '8'` in `$Text`.

Note 2: Below is the expected print from the `print_r($NewArray)`:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[1] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[2] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[4] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[5] => Array ( [JOE] => 3 ) 
[6] => Array ( [JOE.] => 4 ) 
[7] => Array ( [, JOE.] => 1 ) 
[8] => Array ( [,JOE.] => 8 ) 
[9] => Array ( [, JOE.] => 1 ) 
[10] => Array ( [JOE/.] => 7 ) 
[11] => Array ( [,JOE.] => 8 ) 
[12] => Array ( [/JOE/] => 6 ) 
[13] => Array ( [, JOE] => 2 ) )
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Take a look at Elasticsearch and Solr. They are both derived from Lucene, but are much easier to use from PHP.

Comment: @LaurynasTretjakovas, thanks for your comment, unfortunately I'm not a professional programmer, could you please give me an example how to use Elasticsearch or Solr in my problem?

Answer (score 0):

After you have sorted the keyrwords from longest to shortest, you know that a string will be checked before any possible subsets of that string (/JOE/ before /JOE). So you can use `str_replace` to remove the actual matches, hence do not match /JOE/ when searching for /JOE (assuming you have searched for /JOE/ before). Use the `count` parameter of [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) to get the count of matched items

```
<?php
$Keywords = array(
            ', JOE.' => '1',
            ', JOE' => '2',
            'JOE' => '3',
            'JOE.' => '4',
            '/JOE' => '5',
            '/JOE/' => '6',
            'JOE/.' => '7',
            ',JOE.' => '8'
    );
$Text = "JOE is JOE. Hello , JOE. Hey ,JOE. Come on , JOE. Dude,JOE/. Shut up ,JOE. What is the meaning of /JOE/? Of course, JOE";

uksort($Keywords, function ($a, $b) {
        $as = mb_strlen($a);
        $bs = mb_strlen($b);

        if ($as > $bs) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if ($bs > $as) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    });

$copy = $Text;
foreach ($Keywords as $keyword => $value) {
   $copy = str_replace($keyword, '', $copy, $count);
   if ($count > 0) {
       $result[$keyword] = $value;
   }
}

print_r($result);
```

You can use the $count variable to actually count how many times the string was present.

Comment: thanks for your answer. when I echo `print_r($Keywords_ci);` in the current code, I get the same results as your `print_r($result);`. However, what I'm looking is after that, to enhance the quality of the matching based on the number of the available keywords,

Comment: @Apiah can you add the expected output ?